# Center of mass and a grand jeté

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider a grand jeté.

When the ballet dancer jumps up the arms and legs are lifted in order to raise the center of mass. When the ballet dancer reaches a max height the legs and arms goes down in order to lower the center of mass. The reason for this movement pattern is to have the torso and head move in a flatter curve than the parabolic curve of the center of mass. This in order to give an illusion of the ballet dancer floating through the air.

I understand that the center of mass ALWAYS follows a parabolic curve.

However, I am having trouble intuitively understanding exactly why the head and the torso of the ballet dancer is NOT doing the same. Why/how does the torso and head remain stationary in the air for longer? Is it because there are other forces (from the moving limbs) acting upon them? Something else?

Thanks

Comment: I admit to being a bit lost here, this is simply an optical illusion (that is, a  trick) that ballet dancers learn. They spend time practicing  holding (after the initial movement into the correct position) their limbs and head to prolong the effect. That's the other forces, internal dancer controlled forces, in other words.

Comment: But if it is just an optical illusion then how come the head and torso actually DO NOT follow a curve similar to the curve of the center of mass? I mean, it's not like the ballet dancer is able to change the position of the head/torso during flight like it's possible to do with the extremities.

Here is another video illustrating what I am talking about: https://www.instagram.com/p/BbgIhAuni7x/?taken-by=josh_bhebhe

Notice the hang time of the feet that seems to stay stationary in the air for longer than they "should".

Answer (score 0):

This answer based around HRW, and the advice of a friend who wanted to be a ballet dancer, until she found out how much practice it took :). Also, as you point out, my comment is (mostly) incorrect, my apologies for that.

The Grande Jete takes advantage of the fact that the ballerina is able to alter the position of her legs (in particular, moving them into a split position at the apex of the jump). There is a trick though, in that, although the initial jump carries the ballerina through path of forward motion, and therefore she should follow a parabolic path, the centre of gravity can be moved by altering the position of the (not inconsiderable mass, of even a ballerina's legs), as mentioned above. The c.o.g. is then raised closer to the head, which itself is tilted backwards as the jump is carried out.

The head's position (or another fixed point on the body) then has a smaller  **vertical** displacement than the c.o.g undergoes.

Final result: this all acts to allow the head to conform to a flatter trajectory, making it appear that the ballerina is floating across the stage.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. 

However, I still don't quite get it. If you take a look at the instagram video I posted, how is the legs able to stay stationary in the air for such a long time when the jumper moves his arms downwards? Yes, I understand that the COM is not stationary, but I am still having a hard time understanding WHY his legs remains stationary in the air.

Comment: And here is the jumping video I am referring to: https://www.reddit.com/r/sports/comments/7eq26a/josh_imatorbhebhe_with_the_hang_time/

Comment: Hi David, on my tablet, the link gives me an Instagram 404 page. Can I ask you to read through this page, as it goes into more detail than the above. https://sites.google.com/site/icgrandjete/science-of-grand-jete

Comment: I read through the page but it didn't answer my question. I do understand that the COM follows a parabolic curve and that because a person isn't a rigid object the COM can be manipulated in the air. However, what I do not understand is how some parts of the body can follow a parabolic curve while other do not. For instance, in the video below, how come the feet stay in the air for so long? is it because of the forces of the arms pulling the torso up/down? The instagram video I linked to can also be seen here: https://www.reddit.com/r/sports/comments/7eq26a/josh_imatorbhebhe_with_the_hang_time/

Comment: What is HRW? Please do not use acronyms without explaining them.